# Format struct data in watch view

Tags: c#, struct

Whan I have a Datetime type object in my code such as

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
```

and if I add it to Watch Window and it is displayed in such a format :
[image]

But when I create such a struct and add it to Watch Window it looks like :
[image]
I can see the name of my struct, and properties if I expand the tree. But I would like to see a formatted view of my current data.

What should I do to my struct to look like DateTime in the Watch Window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to override the ToString() method of the struct.
The value you return will be the one displayed in the watch window.

```
struct Foo {
    public int Bar;

    public Foo(int bar) {
        Bar = bar;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return Bar.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. That does the trick. I can't believe it is so easy. I have used ToString() method several times but never noticed it changes Watch Window display this way.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` :

```
[DebuggerDisplay("StartHour = {StartHour}")]
public struct Scheduler
{
    public DateTime StartHour;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. That works pretty well. But previous answer returns the string as the DateTime does. But yours is also a very good alternative approach as far as I can see.